# Change the value of column on selecting dropdown option from other column ejs-grid inline editing

Tags: angular, grid, ejs

```
<e-column field="itemName" headerText="{{ 'itemName' | translate }}" [filter]="filter"
clipMode="EllipsisWithTooltip" width="20%" editType="dropdownedit" [edit]="priorityParams">
</e-column>

<e-column field="itemCost" format="C2" headerText="{{ 'itemCost' | translate }}"
[filter]="filter" clipMode="EllipsisWithTooltip" width="20%" editType='numericedit'  [validationRules]='numericRule'></e-column>


component.ts
this.priorityParams = {
    params: {
        actionComplete: () => false,
        allowFiltering: true,
        dataSource: new DataManager(this.vendorLineItemData),
        fields: { text: 'itemCodeName', value: 'itemCodeName' },
        query: new Query(),
        change: (args) => this.valChange(args)
    }
};

valChage(args){
    const formEle = (this.PODetailslineitemsgrid as any).element.querySelector('form').ej2_instances[0];
    formEle.getInputElement('itemCost').value = 100;
}
```

After selecting different option from dropdown list of itemName inline grid editng `valChange()` method should set itemCost column value of selected row to 100.
but it is not updating the column itemCost value and not reflecting in column in edit mode.